# AutoHotkey - Building a Clipboardsaving Function

Tags: function, variables, autohotkey, clipboard

What I want to do is to build a function, that I can use to paste something (in this case URLs). Normally I would just use the send command or the sendinput command, but they are kind of slow which is a little bit annoying. That's why I want to avoid it and use the clipboard instead.

Here my function:

```
ClipPaster(CustomClip){
        ClipSaved := ClipboardAll ;Saving the current clipboard
        Clipboard := %CustomClip% ;Overwriting the current clipboard
        Send, ^{v}{Enter} ;pasting it into the search bar
        Clipboard := Clipsaved ;Recovering the old clipboard
    }
```

Here how I'm using the function:

```
RAlt & b::
   Send, ^{t} ;Open a new tab
   ClipPaster("chrome://settings/content/images") ;Activating my clipboard   
   return
```

```
RAlt & g::
   Send, ^{t} ;Open a new tab
   ClipPaster("https://translate.google.com/#en/es/violin") ;Activating 
   my clipboard function
   return
```

Then when I'm trying to use the function. I get an error:
Error: The following variable name contains an illegal character: "chrome://settings/content/images"
Line:
-->1934: Clipboard := %CustomClip%

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error message because

> **Variable names in an expression are NOT enclosed in percent signs.**

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Expressions

```
ClipPaster(CustomClip){
        ClipSaved := ClipboardAll  ; Saving the current clipboard
        Clipboard := ""            ; empty the clipboard (start off empty to allow ClipWait to detect when the text has arrived)
        ; Variable names in an expression are NOT enclosed in percent signs:
        Clipboard := CustomClip    ; Overwriting the current clipboard 
        ClipWait 1                 ; wait max. 1 second for the clipboard to contain data
        if (!ErrorLevel)           ; If NOT ErrorLevel clipwait found data on the clipboard
            Send, ^v{Enter}        ; pasting it into the search bar
        Sleep, 300
        Clipboard := Clipsaved     ; Recovering the old clipboard
        ClipSaved := ""            ; Free the memory
    }
```

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm#ClipboardAll

Comment: Ok, that makes sense! I tried to do it without the slee time, but for some reason that doesn't work. With the sleep time It works perfectly! Thank you user3419297 :D